# Filter pivot table for specific value

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to filter a pivot that was created using a macro, I will like to filter the table before is created to an specific account number that is 12789

Here is the code that I've been using for the creation of the pivot:

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Set pc = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Range("Bank[#All]"), _
Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

Set pt = ws.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=pc, TableDestination:=Range("AR2"), TableName:="Pivot")


With pt

.PivotFields("narrative_account_number").Orientation = xlRowField
.PivotFields("Debit amount").Orientation = xlDataField

End With
```

Any insight on how to filter the data?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```vb
With pt.PivotFields("narrative_account_number")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    For Each item In .PivotItems
        If item <> "12789" Then item.Visible = False
    Next
End With
pt.PivotFields("Debit amount").Orientation = xlDataField
```